# Angular Shared Service Scope for multiple controllers

Tags: angularjs

I know this has been asked multiple times, i'm trying to share dynamic data with multiple controllers.

Sharing static data was working fine, when i add `$http` i lost the way.

Below is the demo where i'm trying to  implement similar approach.

Demo is working based on static array, i have specified github endpoint which gives similar data.  How to make this demo work based on dynamic data.

```

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('Data', function () {
  return { filtercards: 'Default Data' };
});

myApp.factory('DynamicData', function ($q, $http) {
 var dynamicdataObj = {};

dynamicdataObj.getDynamicData  =  function(type){

   var url = 'https://api.github.com/users/tomalex0/repos'
   $http({
       method: 'GET',
       url: url
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });

};

//dynamicdataObj.lists = dynamicdataObj.getDynamicData('GOOG')

dynamicdataObj.lists = [{
 id : 1,
 name : 'First',
 watchers_count  :5
},{
 id : 2,
 name : 'Second'
}];


return dynamicdataObj;
});

function FirstCtrl($scope, Data, DynamicData) {
 $scope.data = Data;
 $scope.lists = DynamicData.lists;


 $scope.toggleLike = function(item){
  item.watchers_count = (item.watchers_count) ? (item.watchers_count+1) : 1;
 }
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, Data, DynamicData) {
 $scope.data = Data;
 $scope.lists = DynamicData.lists;

}
```

```

http://jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/2j3t6bqh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the array synchronized just update the array with your response without breaking reference and reassigning the array

```
myApp.factory('DynamicData', function ($q, $http) {
   var dynamicdataObj = {
       lists:[]
   };

   dynamicdataObj.getDynamicData  =  function(type){

       var url = 'https://api.github.com/users/tomalex0/repos'
       $http({
           method: 'GET',
           url: url
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
           // concatenate without breaking reference that controllers will have
           dynamicdataObj.lists.concat(response.data)
        }, function errorCallback(response) {

        });

    };
    // load the data when service initializes
     dynamicdataObj.getDynamicData()


   return dynamicdataObj;
});
```

Comment: `concat ` didn't worked,  i tried             `dynamicdataObj.lists.push.apply(dynamicdataObj.lists, response.data);`

Comment: I have updated  the demo  which works fine, http://jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/2j3t6bqh/14/

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

As the http response is asynchronous. You need to get a promise back from your service wait on it and assign the value of $scope.lists once the promise is successfully resolved.

Your DynamicData Factory will be

```
    dynamicdataObj.getDynamicData  =  function(type){

   var url = 'https://api.github.com/users/tomalex0/repos';

   return $http({
       method: 'GET',
       url: url
    });
};
```

and your FirstCtrl will become :

```
function FirstCtrl($scope, Data, DynamicData) {
  $scope.data = Data;  

    //Call GetDynamicData in service and wait till promise gets resolved or rejected.
   DynamicData.getDynamicData()
    .then(function(response){
       //Promise resolved successfully in service, assign the returned data to my lists property
       $scope.lists = response.data;
   },function(err){
       $scope.lists = [];
       console.error('something bad happend');
   })

   $scope.toggleLike = function(item){
     item.watchers_count = (item.watchers_count) ? (item.watchers_count+1) : 1;
   }
}
```

I have updated your jsfiddle with comments for the FirstCtrl here :

http://jsfiddle.net/2j3t6bqh/12/

Comment: Hi,
I have updated SecondCtrl http://jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/2j3t6bqh/11/ . Issue i can see here is change in one controller is not reflected in the other.

If you see here http://jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/2j3t6bqh/. When you `change text` or `like` it  value changes in both controller.

Comment: `$http` already returns  a promise ... it is an anti-pattern to use `$q` as well ... just return `$http`